# Order Sql Request with top Percent

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i have exception when i execute query that i think is well created, the error is : Msg 102, Niveau 15, État 1, Ligne 6
  Syntaxe incorrecte vers ')'.
 here the request :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT designation FROM 
  (select top 100 percent designation , code_piececomptable
  from cpt_lignepiececomptable  WHERE   code_piececomptable IN 
  (SELECT code_piececomptable 
  FROM cpt_piececomptable  WHERE   terminer  is null or terminer <>1) 
  ORDER BY code_piececomptable)
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to `ORDER` a subquery unless it's being used to determine a subset of rows to be returned. The order of the final result set is either determined by an `ORDER BY` on the outermost query or is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give it an alias:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT designation FROM 
  (select top 100 percent designation , code_piececomptable
  from cpt_lignepiececomptable  WHERE   code_piececomptable IN 
  (SELECT code_piececomptable 
  FROM cpt_piececomptable  WHERE   terminer  is null or terminer <>1) 
  ORDER BY code_piececomptable) q
```

Take note to the `q` tacked on to the end.

Answer (score 0):

select top 100 percent designation   from cpt_lignepiececomptable  WHERE   code_piececomptable IN 
  (SELECT code_piececomptable 
  FROM cpt_piececomptable  WHERE   terminer  is null or terminer <>1) 
  ORDER BY code_piececomptable

I think Order by gives error in Subqueries.

Try using this

Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Comment: it throw the same exception Mr Ashutosh !!

Comment: Of course, now that it's not a subquery, you don't need the `TOP 100 PERCENT` nonsense either.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, please watch out. if you applie distinct in fron of the query the result will be exactly same.

Answer (score 0):

As for the error, mentioned in the other answer it is because you have to alias you sub-queries if you are selecting from it.

However, you can completely rewrite your query here not to use sub-queries at all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT designation
FROM cpt_lignepiececomptable lpc
INNER JOIN cpt_piececomptable cpc ON lpc.code_piececomptable = cpc.code_piececomptable
WHERE cpc.terminer IS NULL OR cpc.terminer <>1
ORDER BY lpc.code_piececomptable
```